# Define an operator in prolog

Tags: prolog, operators, iso-prolog

I need to define a new operator that associates in the following way

```
 (1 newop 2) / (2 newop) / a
```

The parenthesis were just used to give an understanding of the associativity of the new op

So.

```
:- op(A, B, newop).
```

Which would be the values for A and B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's impossible. Do you want to discriminate number vs atom ?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is that `newop` serves both as an infix operator as in `(1 newop 2)` and as a postfix operator as in `(2 newop)`.

This is impossible in ISO Prolog. In subclause 6.3.4.3 of ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 it is stated:

> There shall not be an infix and a postfix operator with the same name.

That said, there are implementations that still permit this. However, be aware that such implementations ofter differ in [subtle ways](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment#237).

Answer (score 0):

infix operator: xfx

precende should be higher than "/"

precende for / is 400

```
 :- op (300, xfx, newop).
```

Comment: That takes care of the infix case on your original example, but not the post fix case.